# NSTextView add URL link to the selected Text?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I Have an `NSTextView`.

I just want to add an Attribute (an `NSLinkAttributeName`) to the selected Text in the `NSTextView`...

Can You Help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to get the view's textStorage (which is basically a mutable attributed string), then add the `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute to the selected range; the value of that attribute is the URL to link to.

```
[[textView textStorage] addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: url range:[textView selectedRange]];
```

Comment: [[[textView textStorage] attributedSubstringFromRange:[textView selectedRange]] attribute:NSLinkAttributeName atIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL];

Comment: [[textView textStorage] removeAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName range:[textView selectedRange]];

Answer (score -1):

Been a while since I played with ObjC but this should do the trick. It replaces the selected text with the original content with your attr appended. Checked through it but please excuse any typos.

```
NSTextView *textView = ...;
NSDictionary *attributes = ...;

//Get selected text string from TextView (see Text superclass) and append attr link
NSRange selRange = [textView selectedRange];
NSMutableString *changedStr = [[[textView string] substringWithRange:selRange] mutableCopy];
[changedStr appendString:[attributes objectForKey:NSLinkAttributeName]];

//Replace the selected text range in the TextView
[textView replaceCharactersInRange:selRange withString:[NSString stringWithString:changedStr]];

[changedStr release];
```

See class defs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html

- -replaceCharactersInRange:withString:
- -selectedRange
- -scrollRangeToVisible:    if you want to present your change immediately

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

- substringWithRange:

Comment: Nope; that's going to append a URL to the visible text, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Oh, ok. apologies Le roukin. Misunderstood the question.

Comment: Hi, yes, this answer's wrong but I've left it for posterity (or for anyone else for whom `NSLinkAttributeName` is new territory), rather than delete it. My Objective-C is a little out of date (esp in 2011) but in process of being refreshed.